# What is this Bash Syntax in FizzBuzz Example

Tags: bash, fizzbuzz

I just found the following FizzBuzz example on Hacker News and it uses a piece of syntax I'm finding it difficult to search for

```
for num in {1..100} ; do
  out=""
  (( $num % 3 == 0 )) && out="Fizz"
  (( $num % 5 == 0 )) && out="${out}Buzz"
  echo ${out:-$num}
done
```

The bit I don't understand is how the variable usage works in the `echo` line. Though I can obviously see that it becomes `$out` if not empty, else `$num`

Comment: It is a default `:-`, if out is nothing print the number. Second piece of code on here http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Answer (score 4):

```
for num in {1..100} ; do
```

Loop from 1 to 100.Set num to each integer on the way

```
out=""
```

Set out to nothing

```
(( $num % 3 == 0 )) && out="Fizz"
```

If the number is divisible by 3 set out to Fizz

```
  (( $num % 5 == 0 )) && out="${out}Buzz"
```

If the number is divisible by 5 set `out` to whatever is contained in `out` then Buzz.

```
  echo ${out:-$num}
```

Uses parameter substitution to check that out contains something, if it does not, then use num instead.
Echos result of the substitution.

```
done
```

---

Resources

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html - parameter substitution

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html - let command `((...))`

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html - loops

Comment: @PeterR I rejected the edit as although it contains some information you may not have wanted, it may be useful for others. It isn't too long for the information you did want to be easily locatable.

Comment: It is at the very end of the post, and there are plenty of easily searchable posts that cover the other material. I am very thankful you took the time to help me and you don't have to edit your post, but I also don't have to set best answer - though I would very much like to be able to